# Method in null class pointer (c++)

Tags: c++, null

Let's say whe have

```
class Foo{

public:
       bool   error;
       ......
       bool isValid(){return error==false;}
};
```

and somewhere

```
Foo *aFoo=NULL;
```

I usually would do `if (aFoo!=NULL && aFoo->isValid()).....`

But what if in the isValid method I test the nullity:

```
bool isValid(){return this!=NULL && error==false)
```

That would simplify the external testing with simply calling `if (aFoo->isValid())`

I've tested it in some compilers and it works but I wonder if it is standard and could cause problems when porting to other environments.

Comment: I don't know if it is valid, but I think that even if it is. Any way in my opinion it may be very hard to maintain a client code which assume that the class method implementation checks for nullity.

Comment: it is definitely not valid to dereference a nullptr

Comment: Im not quite sure, but I believe this cannot work as `this` within a class cannot be `NULL`, which means that the check in the method is unnecessary; on the other hand, a method call on a null object is undefined behaviour. Is that right?

Comment: `I've tested it in some compilers and it works`  One of the worst ways to determine if a C++ construct is valid or not.

Comment: Yes @PaulMcKenzie, but that was only the firs step. Second one is checking in StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply a namespace-scope function like this?

```
bool isValid(Foo* f) {return f && f->isValid();}
```

An `if`-Statement like

```
if (aFoo->isValid())
```

Implies that the pointer is pointing to a valid object. It would be a huge source of confusion and very error prone.

Finally, your code would indeed invoke undefined behavior - `aFoo->isValid` is per definition equivalent to `(*aFoo).isValid`:

> **N3337, §5.2.5/2**
>
> The expression `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form
>   `(*(E1)).E2`;

which would dereference a null pointer to obtain a null reference, which is clearly undefined:

> **N3337, §8.3.2/5**
>
> [ Note: in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the
>   “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer, which causes
>   undefined behavior. […] — end note ]

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is free to optimize away the check -- calling any non-static member of any class through an invalid (or `NULL` pointer) is undefined behavior. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 4):

Generally it would be bad design and in standard C++ it doesn't make much sense as your internal NULL check implies that you would call a null pointer, which is undefined behavior.

This topic was discusses here:
[Checking if this is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844005/checking-if-this-is-null)