# Does this function for detecting integer addition overflow actually work?

Tags: c++, c, integer-overflow

While reading the comments for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893251/why-does-the-enhanced-gcc-6-optimizer-break-practical-c-code), I came across a link to the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/misc/intovf.html) that shows a "careful addition function" which purportedly detects integer overflow:

```
int
chkadd(int a, int b)
{
    if (INT_MAX - b < a) {
        fputs("int overflow\n", stderr);
        return INT_MAX;
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

How does this not overflow if `b == -1`? If the assumption is that `a` and `b` are both positive, why make them `int` rather than `unsigned int` in the first place?

Comment: because `INT_MAX - (-1)` equals `INT_MIN`?

Comment: Signed `int` **might** wrap: but it is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Assumes `a` and `b` are positive. Useful for converting strings to `int` while checking for overflow.

Comment: Don't spin your own, google "safeint library".

Comment: @ddz In C, `INT_MAX - (-1)` is undefined behavior.  A compiler can optimize that code to any answer including `INT_MIN, 0, or 42` and still be a compliant compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably they just overlooked it. [Additional links](http://c-faq.com/misc/sd26.html) on the FAQ page seem to provide more correct code.

Comment: And those will fail if `b == INT_MIN`, but at least they mention it. I guess it's really just not as easy as they pretend, which is also my experience...

Comment: That's what they also say in the "correct code": (Note: these functions all share one bug: they may fail if invoked on the largest negative integer, INT_MIN.).

Answer (score 4):

OP has identified that `INT_MAX - b` may overflow, rendering the remaining code invalid for proper overflow detection.  It does not work.

```
if (INT_MAX - b < a) {  // Invalid overflow detection
```

A method to detect overflow without UB follows:

```
int is_undefined_add1(int a, int b) {
  return (a < 0) ? (b < INT_MIN - a) : (b > INT_MAX - a);
}
```

---

> why make them `int` rather than `unsigned int` in the first place?

Changing to `unsigned` does not solve the problem *in general*.  The range of `unsigned: [0...UINT_MAX]` could be half of that of `int: [INT_MIN...INT_MAX]`.  IOWs: `INT_MAX == UINT_MAX`.  Such systems are rare these days.  IAC, changing types is not needed as coded with `is_undefined_add1()`.