# getting virtual table pointer c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class such as

```
class Stuff
{
private:
int x;
virtual int buisness()
{
  return 42;
}
public:
 Stuff(){
  x = 5;
}
```

Given a pointer to an instance of this class

```
Stuff stuff;
void* thing = &stuff;
```

How would I get a pointer to the variable x and a pointer to the virtual function table of that class using just the pointer "thing"?

Edit:  to clarify this was a challenge sent to me and I have been assured that it is not a trick question.

Comment: The implementation of virtual function tables is compiler dependent.  There is not even a requirement to use virtual function tables.

Comment: Please update your question to show how you would use a pointer to a virtual function table (why do you *need* a pointer to the function table?).

Comment: This question is hard to understand because it's not clear what context you are asking it in. Are you asking how to modify the code? How to add existing code without changing that code? How to do it with a debugger? It would help an awful lot to understand what problem you are trying to solve with this as that would make the context clear.

Comment: Why do you want to see the virtual function table ? I am too curious to know

Comment: Hmmm, for downvoters and arguers from all above comments, the question is pretty straight forward, isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How would I get a pointer to the variable x and a pointer to the virtual function table of that class using just the pointer "thing"?

You can't without casting `thing` back to the original type:

```
Stuff* stuff2 = reinterpret_cast<Stuff*>(thing);
```

and at least that doesn't redeem you from privacy policies of that class, and how you could access class member pointers publicly.

The actual layout is implementation defined, and trying to use offsets from *thing* and size assumptions is beyond standard c++ mechanisms.

---

It sounds like you want to circumvent the `private` member access policies of a class with known layout of these members. Here's an extremely dirty hack:
<sub>**Disclamer:** Don't do that in production code!!</sub>

```
#include <iostream>

class Stuff {
private:
    int x;
    virtual int business() {
        std::cout << "Have that 42 ... " << std::endl;
        return 42;
    }
public:
    Stuff() {
      x = 5;
    }
};

struct StuffProxy {
    // Make the layout public:
    int x;
    virtual int business();
};

int main() {
    Stuff stuff;
    void* thing = &stuff;

    // Here's the nasty stuff
    StuffProxy* stuffProxy = reinterpret_cast<StuffProxy*>(thing);
    int* addrX = &(stuffProxy->x); // Get the address of x
    std::cout << "x = " << *addrX << std::endl;

    typedef int (Stuff::*StuffFunc)();
    StuffFunc stuffFunc = (StuffFunc)(&StuffProxy::business);
    std::cout << "business() = " << (stuff.*stuffFunc)() << std::endl;
}
```

---

Output:

```
x = 5
Have that 42 ... 
business() = 42
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4fc1f944e7a1f67)

The above works because it's guaranteed that `class` and `struct` will have the same layout in a c++ compilers implementation, with the only difference of the members visibility during compilation.

So if you have the layout of a class (e.g. from a header), and you are willing to maintain that over the lifetime of your project, you can provide such proxy like above to access the `private` stuff from a class.

Answer (score 2):

To access the `private` member `x`:

1) Declare the function, that needs to access `x`, as a friend of the class.

2) Change access to `public`.

3) Write public *getter* or *setter* functions.

4) Change your design; Other classes should not know about member variables.

Comment: You can well circumvent all of these rules (not that I recommend so), unless you hide everything beyond a `pimpl` (and best use unnamed namespaces for the actual implementation).

Answer (score 0):

This may be compiler dependant.
I just made a char array from the pointer "thing"

```
char *array;
array = (char*)thing;
```

Then traverse that array until I found the private variables

```
int x = array[8];
```