# How Foo *p = 0;p->p() is valid?

Tags: c++

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int i)
    {
        _i = i;
    }
    void p()
    {
        cout<<"printed"<<endl;
    }
    int _i;
};
int main()
{
    Foo *p = 0;
    cout <<p<<endl;
    p->p();

    return 0;
}
```

The actual output of above code is

```
0
printed
```

As per my understanding it should give SEG fault for accessing 0x0 addess.
Because the *p address is 0x0.

Why it is working ?anybody explain it ?

Comment: This is [*Undefined Behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Anything can happen, up to and including *appearing* to work. In this case, if you really want to see a crash, try having a member variable in `Foo`, which you print in `Foo::p()`, to actually force the computer to try to access some memory at the invalid address.

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer is always undefined behavior. *However*, you're "just" calling a member function, and for that the compiler doesn't actually dereference the pointer, it just jumps to some code. It would be a very different matter if you used `this` inside the function (for example to print the value of `_i`).

Comment: Because in truth `*p` isn't dereferenced anywhere. A method of a class has an hidden parameter containing the `this`, so your call is translated to `methodp(pointerp)`; no dereferencing. Note that if `methodp` was `virtual`, then you surely would have gotten a crash

Comment: When you invoke Undefined Behavior as you did, your program is free from any semantic guarantees of the C++ language.

Comment: If you *really want* to increase your odds of a fault, add `<< _i` to your output in `p()`.  Regardless, you're invoking *undefined behavior*. Consider yourself *unlucky* it didn't crash when you expected it to.

Answer (score 4):

It is not valid. But *undefined beheviour* doesn't guarantee segfaults or anything.

You can't rely on anything here, so don't do it. It can (appear to) work, it can crash, it can burn your computer, anything.

In this particular case, the method p() does not depend on anything else in its class, and the compiler is allowed to assume that you have no UB in your code, so it most likely just executes p without even doing anything with the pointer (but again, there is no guarantee that the compiler is working like that).

Comment: it can't burn your computer

Comment: @user Sure it can. It can even kill people (and did that already).

Comment: I wouldn't say "it can work", because there is no correct behaviour defined. Logically, it can't work.

Comment: it can't make ETs invade the earth either

Comment: I would change "it can work" to "it can seem to work"

Comment: @user ...but it can make demons come out of your nose. Yeah, we won't get alien invasions. Are you satisfied now?

Comment: Can you also provide reference that this specific case will lead to undefined behavior?  I am very curious!

Comment: Still there is no response to *Why it is working*? There is an explanation about why this UB is often implemented in that way.

Comment: @xanatos It's working because the compilers understand what you are trying to do. Again, undefined behaviour means that the compilers are allowed to do anything, including what the programmer intended.

Comment: @Aziuth No, it is working because the `*p` isn't dereferenced. The compiler isn't "understanding" anything. There could be 1,000,000 reasons why the compiler could choose to dereference `*p` (for example for security checking, or for logging, or ???), but often compilers won't do it unless it is requested by the program or the function is virtual.

Comment: @xanatos You are speaking of this behaviour as far too certain, as if this was how it has to be done in any case. What you describe is what a compiler *might* do. A compiler could also be programmed to dereference anyway in this case. Inefficient, granted, but valid. And yes, "understanding" is the right word here.

Comment: @Aziuth My point on your response was that by using the verb "understand" you imply that this case happened because the compiler did something "active" to make it happen. On the opposite, it happened because the compiler (and the runtime, because pointer dereferencing is done at runtime) did nothing, so for a chain of fate the code ran without apparent problems.

Comment: One example of what a compiler can do with this kind of shenanigans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893251/why-does-the-enhanced-gcc-6-optimizer-break-practical-c-code

Answer (score -5):

Because *p()* is a normal method (i.e. not virtual), the call to *p->p()* can be resolved at compile time, and since you don't access any members of *p* a valid *this* pointer is not needed inside the method.

Edit: .. but as mentioned above, this is actually undefined behaviour.

Comment: This answer is incomplete (and dangerous) without mentioning that while this is why it appears to work in practice, it's still Undefined behaviour.