# Why is "this" NULL? C++ Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

[image: Debugger output]

I'm building a Qt app and it's crashing because of a segmentation fault. After investigation, I found out that the cause of the segfault is that "this" is NULL and I try to access a member variable in the readInputFile(QString path) method.
In this line `input += line;`

I don't understand why this is happening. how can "this" be NULL ?

**Here's where the object is created**

```
void MainWindow::on_inpFileCheck_clicked()
{
    if (ui->inpFileCheck->isChecked()) {
        QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open CSV file"), "/home", tr("CSV  (*.csv)"));
        myAlgo->readInputFile(filePath);
        ui->inputEdit->clear();
        ui->inputEdit->appendPlainText(myAlgo->getInput());
    }
}
```

**Here's the BaseAlgorithm header**

```
#include "qstring.h"
#include "qmainwindow.h"

class BaseAlgorithm
{
public:
    BaseAlgorithm();
    QString readInputFile(QString);
    int lenArr;

private:
    QString input;
    QString output;
};
```

**And here's the implementation and where the problem happens**

```
#include "basealgorithm.h"
#include "qfile.h"
#include "qtextstream.h"

BaseAlgorithm::BaseAlgorithm() {

    numComparisons = 0;
    input = "";
    output = "";
    intArr = NULL;
}

QString BaseAlgorithm::readInputFile(QString path) {

    QFile inpFile(path);
    if (inpFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        QTextStream in(&inpFile);

        while (!in.atEnd()) {
            QString line = in.readLine();
            input += line; // crash happens here
        }
        return input;
    }

    else {
         return "ERROR";
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does it crash?

Comment: @DeiDei Updated. In the readInputFile() method. This line `input += line;`

Comment: Hard to say much without knowing where and how `BaseAlgorithm` is created. I recommend fashioning yourself an [mcve]. If that doesn't show you where the problem is and how to fix it, remove the code in the question and replace it with the MCVE.

Comment: @user4581301 Updated with the recommended fashion.

Comment: You are not showing us where myAlgo gets created.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it. The object was being created late.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, it is perfectly possible to call a method via a null pointer to an object. As long as `this` is not actually dereferenced, the function would work fine.

UPDATE: The behavior is what is often exhibited by implementations, as `this` is usually treated as just another parameter in the compiled code. However, as @manni66 points out, the standard doesn't actually mandate the result of calling a method on a `nullptr`.

Comment: It is UB. The function may do what you expect, but there is **no guarantee**

Comment: I learned something very interesting today.

Comment: Weird things happen if the object is supposed to have a vtable for virtual functions.

Comment: For each undefined behavior the standard states there is usually a well defined behavior in the particular implementation. Implementations tend to go for behavior that is as safe, logical and predictable as possible, contrary to the stereotypical anecdotal UB explanation. It just takes more digging to find that out, and it is really NOT recommended practice to rely on it. It is just tying loose ends to the extent that it is possible in order to avoid the worst as much as possible.

Comment: @dtech The "stereotypical" explanation is actually becoming truer each day as compilers reason more about the values during compile time. Modern C++ compilers are free to and **will** delete method invocations where it's statically known that `this` is null! More generally, the desired and ever more present compiler behavior is to **remove** code with UB. It's an optimization technique, and a very important one. So the "well defined" behavior is that of deleting your code. So yeah - depend on UB as long as you don't care about your code at all. That's the essence of your advice...

Comment: @KubaOber the point was that the behavior is never really undefined in practice. I haven't dug into recent implementations but back in the day when I bothered to check what various compilers do, it was usually the same thing that I would have done. For example the destruction of polymorphic objects without a virtual destructor in the base invoked the destructor for the particular pointer type. And my advise was to NOT rely on that, even if your derived classes don't add anything extra that needs destructing. How you extrapolated the "advice" to depend on UB from my comment is a logical mystery

Comment: @dtech Using UB to mean "remove me" is becoming an idiom. This can't but depend on the ability of the compiler to statically reason about code. So the behavior is "defined" only inasmuch as you can presume that compilers doesn't learn any new tricks. None of is is well documented at all: UB removal depends on implementation details of the various optimization passes. So yes, **with each new modern compiler release the UB is becoming even more undefined** as the optimizers become more complex and delete more UB code - but you never know exactly which code! https://stackoverflow.com/q/36893251

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty obvious that `this` is NULL because `myAlgo` is NULL where it is called. So the question asked in the title here is answered.

Why is `myAlgo` NULL? We don't know because you didn't show that code.