# How Can this == nullptr Ever be true Without Invoking Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, this, undefined-behavior, dereference, nullptr

I was recently reading [Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321992784), and I came upon this snippet inside a function for inserting into a linked list (Page 619):

```
if (n==nullptr) return this;
if (this==nullptr) return n;
```

The first check seems fine, but the second check is very confusing to me. The question that immediately came to my mind is how `this == nullptr` can *ever* be true, considering that `this` would only equal `nullptr` if the object was instantiated as `nullptr`. Since this snippet is in a member function, one would have to dereference a null pointer to access it, which is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793262/why-dereferencing-a-null-pointer-is-undefined-behaviour). To confirm this, I created a small snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() = default;
    void checkSelf()
    {
        if (this == nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "This was nullptr.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "This was not nullptr.\n";
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test* test; // Uninitialized pointer
    test->checkSelf(); // Outputs 'This was nullptr.'

    Test* test2 = nullptr;
    test2->checkSelf(); // Outputs 'This was nullptr.'

    Test* test3 = new Test{}; // Outputs 'This was not nullptr.'
    test3->checkSelf();

    delete test3;
}
```

And just as I expected, only when the pointer was uninitialized as in the first case (Well actually not expected here), or when it was set to `nullptr` as in the second case did the check evaluate to `true` inside the member function. However, since both examples where this was true were examples of undefined behavior, it makes no sense that the check could ever be true in a well-formed program. Thus, Can the check `this == nullptr` ever be true without invoking UB?

[[GCC]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LEzeN6eeOU34KaEo)

Comment: All I can think of is that this slipped in from back when `this` *could* be null.

Comment: @chris Care to elaborate?

Comment: That is a godawful book BTW - Stroustrup has written some good books (The Design and Evolution of C++ is one of my favourites) but he isn't a great teacher.

Comment: @NeilButterworth that may be correct, but one should have some degree of expectations from the first and only book listed for beginners in our [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/6525260)...

Comment: A good explanation about this subject in the answer by Pavel Minaev in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844005/checking-if-this-is-null

Comment: Before the first ISO standard, you could change `this`. [This article](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0355/) goes into more detail. Perhaps incidentally, the author of the code in question is the same in both cases.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Also true. The list should be modified to remove that one from the first place.

Comment: Probably because its the only even half-good book aimed at beginners. And  I will never understand why people would choose C++ as their first language.

Comment: It seems Clang has also answered my question: `warning: 'this' pointer cannot be null in well-defined C++ code; comparison may be assumed to always evaluate to false [-Wtautological-undefined-compare]`

Comment: This has been up before. The example starts in the previous section, where it is not using member functions. Then it is converted to a `Link` class to show that one of the parameters can be replaced by `this`. But the conversion is not done properly, and some `if (p==0)` turned out as `if (this==0)`.

Comment: @BoPersson Ah, that makes sense.